# How to add legend with multiple barplots?

Tags: r

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/R

par(mfrow=c(4,1))

fcm <-c(13.0,12.5,11.8)
gk  <-c(10.9 ,   10.5  ,  10.2)
gg  <-c(12.0 ,   11.0 ,   10.8)
data1 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data1) <- c(5,6,7)

fcm <-c(1.29,1.25,1.22)
gk  <-c(1.19,1.05,1.00)
gg  <-c(1.10,1.02,1.07)
data2 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data2) <- c(5,6,7)

fcm <-c(10.5,9.8,8.8)
gk  <-c(11.0,8.4,10.0)
gg  <-c(2.0,1.8,1.6)
data3 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data3) <- c(5,6,7)

fcm <-c(0.33,0.29,0.31)
gk  <-c(0.49,0.40,0.35)
data4 <- rbind(fcm,gk)
colnames(data4) <- c(5,6,7)

barplot(as.matrix(data1),ylim=c(0,20),main="P wave",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="traveltime rms(ms)",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(data2),ylim=c(0,2),main="MT",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="MT functions",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(data3),ylim=c(0,20),main="XBI",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="index value",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(data4),ylim=c(0,0.6),main="NCE",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="index value",
        col=c("red", "black"), beside=TRUE)

legend(legend = c("fcm","gk","gg"), fill = c( "red", "black", "green"))

dev.copy(png,"dp.png",width=9,height=6,units="in",res=200)
dev.off()
```

I have experimented with legend as a top-right,but it overlaps the image.Anyone knows how to add the legend,location is not so import just to be visible.I am submitting this to a scientific journal I need a nice layout.

Comment: Does it have to be base R? Or can it be ggplot? Best way might be to have four grouped images and one legend on the bottom or top. In general, red and green are not good colors to use, not everyone can see the contrast between them.

Comment: @Heroka It can be ggplot I am allright with that.

Comment: One thing about the legend if you are working with the R gui, is that the first time it writes to a dev.new() the legend is huge and spaced out all weird. Some other options for you is to resize your dev window and then rerun the code, the size of your legend will dramatically change.  Or, you can also write the plots to a file (ex: pdf(width=11, height=8.5) for landscape).

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried to make a nice ggplot-solution for you but I have too many other things to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `layout` instead `par(mfrow...)` and then add the legend where you want.  I have each of your main plots occupying two rows and the legend one row at the bottom.

This example puts the legend at the bottom horizontally.  Unfortunately, I can't upload an image since I'm behind a firewall.

```
layout(matrix(c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5), ncol=1))

# main plots
par(mai=rep(0.5, 4))
fcm <-c(13.0,12.5,11.8)
gk  <-c(10.9 ,   10.5  ,  10.2)
gg  <-c(12.0 ,   11.0 ,   10.8)
data1 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data1) <- c(5,6,7)

fcm <-c(1.29,1.25,1.22)
gk  <-c(1.19,1.05,1.00)
gg  <-c(1.10,1.02,1.07)
data2 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data2) <- c(5,6,7)

fcm <-c(10.5,9.8,8.8)
gk  <-c(11.0,8.4,10.0)
gg  <-c(2.0,1.8,1.6)
data3 <- rbind(fcm,gk,gg)
colnames(data3) <- c(5,6,7)

fcm <-c(0.33,0.29,0.31)
gk  <-c(0.49,0.40,0.35)
data4 <- rbind(fcm,gk)
colnames(data4) <- c(5,6,7)

barplot(as.matrix(data1),ylim=c(0,20),main="P wave",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="traveltime rms(ms)",
       col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(data2),ylim=c(0,2),main="MT",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="MT functions",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(data3),ylim=c(0,20),main="XBI",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="index value",
        col=c("red", "black", "green"), beside=TRUE)
barplot(as.matrix(data4),ylim=c(0,0.6),main="NCE",
        xlab="number of clusters", ylab="index value",
        col=c("red", "black"), beside=TRUE)

# legend for blank plot
par(mai=c(0,0,0,0))
plot.new()
legend(legend = c("fcm","gk","gg"), fill = c( "red", "black", "green"), 
    "center", horiz=TRUE)
```

[image: Output plot with xlab showing]

Comment: Thanks a lot,but the problem is that xlab and ylab labels disappear.The graph itself is perfect.

Comment: You're welcome.  I added a little more margin space with `par(mai=rep(0.5, 4))` and I now see xlab and ylab.  You might play with these parameters, or the layout matrix as desired - e.g., `layout(matrix(c(rep(1, 3), rep(2, 3), rep(3, 3), rep(4, 3), 5), ncol=1))`